# The mother and daughter that went to Mongolia are absolutely wild - why and when we need a "that" in a sentence like this?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I read a sentence:

> The mother and daughter that went to Mongolia are absolutely wild.

Why can't we say directly

> The mother and daughter went to Mongolia are absolutely wild.

In what case should I add the word *that*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relative clause.  See https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar/relative-pronouns-and-relative-clauses

You use a relative clause to describe or identify something.  Here the relative clause "that went to Mongolia" describes "The woman and child".

You need "that" because "The woman and child" is the subject of the relative clause  (*They* went to Mongolia).  You can only omit the word "that" when the thing you are describing is the object of the relative clause:

> The house that fell down is next door  (You need "that")

> The house [that] I built is next door  (You don't need "that")

You need "that" in your sentence in order to identify the main verb of the sentence.  The main verb is "are". If you don't use "that went..." you would think the main verb is "went".